# Dynamically connecting nodes of a graph in QML a la Pd or Max (aka "patching" interface)

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I am trying to mimic a patcher interface in QML, wherein a user can click a node and connect it to another node in the manner shown here:

https://youtu.be/rtgGol-I4gA?t=4m15s

Ultimately connecting these nodes in QML will set pointers in a corresponding C++ graph.  Creating a QML node instantiates a C++ equivalent, so far so good.  For the damn patch itself though, I can't find a smart solution.

I've attempted to make a "patch" class that is instantiated on the first click, then uses drag and drop to connect to the second.  It provides a start and end point so that a canvas can paint the patch (line).  The initial end point is itself, which would be modified once the second node is clicked...

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {

id: root
height: 30
width: 30

property Canvas myCanvas
property var start
property var end

Component.onCompleted: {
    end = root
}

onXChanged: myCanvas.requestPaint()
onYChanged: myCanvas.requestPaint()

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    color: "blue"
    anchors.fill: root

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea

        anchors.fill: rect
        Drag.active: true
        drag.target: root
        drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
        drag.minimumX: 0
        drag.minimumY: 0

        onReleased: mouseArea.Drag.drop()
    }

}
}
```

But setting drag active on creation doesn't work, it still requires a mouse release and another click/drag.  (I can't get the drop to work either, but one problem at a time...)

I'd love some opinions on the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that in `C++` as a one solid item, a "field". I mean to paint all the nodes and "patches" inside this item, implementing `QQuickItem` or `QQuickPaintedItem`. So you will be able to reimplement all the mouse events as you want. Also you can do all the work with `Canvas`, for example:

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
impor

Window
{
    id: mainWindow
    width: 800
    height: 800
    x: (Screen.width - width) / 2
    y: (Screen.height - height) / 2
    visible: true

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        property var objects: []
        property var connections: []
        property int objectSize: 50
        property int objectCount: 30
        property point startPoint: Qt.point(0,0)
        property point endPoint: Qt.point(0,0)
        anchors.fill: parent
        focus: true
        Component.onCompleted: {
            fillField();
        }

        function fillField() {
            for(var i = 0;i < canvas.objectCount;i ++) {
                do {
                    var x = canvas.objectSize + Math.round(Math.random() * (mainWindow.width - canvas.objectSize * 2));
                    var y = canvas.objectSize + Math.round(Math.random() * (mainWindow.height - canvas.objectSize * 2));
                    if(checkCoord(x, y) === true) {
                        objects.push(Qt.point(x,y));
                        break;
                    }
                } while(true);
            }
            canvas.requestPaint();
        }

        function checkCoord(_x, _y) {
            for(var i = 0;i < objects.length;i ++) {
                if(Math.abs(objects[i].x - _x) < canvas.objectSize &&
                        Math.abs(objects[i].y - _y) < canvas.objectSize) {
                    return objects[i];
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1,1,1,1);
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
            ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1);
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.lineJoin = "round";
            for(var i = 0;i < objects.length;i ++) {
                ctx.ellipse(objects[i].x - canvas.objectSize/2,objects[i].y - canvas.objectSize/2,canvas.objectSize,canvas.objectSize);
            }
            if(startPoint.x !== 0 && startPoint.y !== 0) {
                ctx.moveTo(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
                ctx.lineTo(endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, 1);
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            for(var i = 0;i < connections.length;i ++) {
                ctx.moveTo(connections[i].start.x, connections[i].start.y);
                ctx.lineTo(connections[i].end.x, connections[i].end.y);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1,1,0,1);
            for(var i = 0;i < connections.length;i ++) {
                ctx.ellipse(connections[i].start.x - 5, connections[i].start.y - 5, 10, 10);
                ctx.ellipse(connections[i].end.x - 5, connections[i].end.y - 5, 10, 10);
            }
            ctx.fill();
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                var point = canvas.checkCoord(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                if(point !== true) {
                    canvas.startPoint = point;
                }
                else
                    canvas.startPoint = Qt.point(0,0);
            }
            onReleased: {
                if(canvas.startPoint.x === 0 && canvas.startPoint.y === 0)
                    return;
                var point = canvas.checkCoord(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                if(point === true)
                    canvas.startPoint = Qt.point(0,0);
                else {
                    if(point.x !== canvas.startPoint.x || point.y !== canvas.startPoint.y) {
                        canvas.connections.push({
                                                    start: Qt.point(canvas.startPoint.x,canvas.startPoint.y),
                                                    end: Qt.point(point.x, point.y)
                                                });
                    }
                    canvas.startPoint = Qt.point(0,0);
                }
                canvas.requestPaint();
            }
            onPositionChanged: {
                if(canvas.startPoint.x !== 0 && canvas.startPoint.y !== 0){
                    canvas.endPoint = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                    canvas.requestPaint();
                }
            }
        }

        Keys.onPressed: {
            switch(event.key)
            {
            case Qt.Key_Escape:
                canvas.objects = [];
                canvas.connections = [];
                canvas.startPoint = Qt.point(0,0);
                canvas.endPoint = Qt.point(0,0);
                canvas.fillField();
                break;
            case Qt.Key_Backspace:
                canvas.connections.pop();
                canvas.requestPaint();
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: " Esc - rearange, Backspace - undo ";
    }

    Text {
        text: "Draw your own constellation"
        font.bold: true
        font.capitalization: Font.AllUppercase
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
    }
}
```